# Ghostscript On windows leads to Invalid option for -dPDFSETTINGS

Tags: windows, bash, pdf, ghostscript, cmder

To solve my problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/525486/102825) with compressing/down-sizing a PDF file generated by MikTeX on Windows, I am trying [this bash script](http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/) on Cmder as:

```
shrinkpdf.sh in.pdf > out.pdf
```

However I get the error:

> Invalid value for option -dPDFSETTINGS=C:/Program Files/Git/screen, use -sNAME= to define string constants

which I suppose has to do with the line

```
-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

My environment is:

- Windows OS: `1809`
- Cmder: `1.3.14`
- Ghostscript: `9.27`

Comment: I'm running the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @MHogge my apologies, this is a question from a while ago and I do not remember if/how I solved it.

Comment: No worries I finally found the solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue and I fixed it using a double slash: "//screen" instead of "/screen". This is due to mingw that is trying to be smart and replace "/" with GIT home directory.

Reference: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24029#issuecomment-250412919

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be a Ghostscript problem. It seems to be something to do with your script, presumably some kind of argument replacement or expansion.

Claearly this:

> -dPDFSETTINGS=C:/Program Files/Git/screen

is incorrect, but that's nothing to do with Ghostscript. I suspect you neeed to quote that argument or something like that, so that your shell doesn't meddle with it.

Comment: you mean I need to use `"/screen"` instead?

Comment: I cannot answer that question, since I don't use Cmder or have your installation. You need to find out what is turnning '/screen' into "C:/Program Files/Git/screen". To me that looks like the shell has seen what it thinks is a path specifier , the '/' in '/screen', and replaced it with a prefix pointing to a Git installation. I have no idea why that's happened, but its nothing to do with Ghostscript, its (presumably) cmder, since that's what is interpreting the script.